# Serde Serializer example contains errors

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to create a custom serializer using serde. I copy and pasted the code at: https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html

The only thing I changed was I didn't use `error::Result`, and I am instead using `anyhow::Result`. `error::Result` does not exist and that is why.

The error I'm getting is `` trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword ``. So what I did was go to all instances of `type Error = Error;` and replaced it with `type Error = dyn Error;`

Doing so, I get several more errors. I get `` the size for values of type `dyn error::Error` cannot be known at compilation time ``,  `` `dyn error::Error` cannot be shared between threads safely ``, `` the size for values of type `(dyn error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time ``, and `mismatched types`.

I figured that to get rid of the last error I could just do `Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error>` and get rid of the `use anyhow::Result;` at the top.

It's the other errors I'm not sure how to get rid of is the issue. I'm relatively new to Rust, and I'm just not sure of all the proper things to do in this type of situation.

Comment: I don't get "trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword", I get plenty of errors about `anyhow::Error` not implementing `serde::ser::Error`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5785d55cc5156f7d68093894d48de884.

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here is the exact code I am using.
https://pastebin.com/ZwG7qps8

Comment: @TiredFox07 please do not share links to external platforms, and include all information required to reproduce your problem here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation of serde_json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) is a good reference for defining custom serializers.

In the provided custom serializer example, it just uses the `use error::{Error, Result};` as a placeholder for any serialization errors, they don't actually exist.

What you should do is define your own error type for your serializer, possibly making use of the [thiserror crate](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror), and remove any of the `dyn` markers as the error is now a concrete type.

An example of such:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
#[error("My custom serializer error: {0}")]
pub struct Error(String);

pub type Result<T> = core::result::Result<T, Error>;

impl ser::Error for Error {
    fn custom<T>(msg: T) -> Self where T: Display {
        Error(msg.to_string())
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Is it normal for examples to have placeholders such as that? Or is that just something that serde does?

Comment: @TiredFox07 I’ve seen it somewhat often, usually documentation authors will omit those things as to not distract from the main point of the example, although it is still helpful to clarify such.